# Xcode: ipatool failed with an exception

Tags: ios, xcode

On export .ipa file I am getting below **error**:

```
ipatool failed with an exception: #<CmdSpec::NonZeroExcitException: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/bitcode-build-tool exited with pid 45488 exit 1
Stdout:
    Debug: SDK path: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.2.sdk
    Debug: PATH: ['/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin', '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin']
    Debug: Using: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo
    MachoInfo: cd /
    "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo" "-info" "/var/folders/54/vkh5d7bx5s3cq3yb4_zshfmh0000gn/T/ipatool20180623-43023-bh0irk/thinned/armv7/Payload/test.app/Frameworks/Quickblox.framework/Quickblox"
```

Comment: What code have you written? Please add to the question the function that is causing the error

Comment: @aydow this error show when last level for export ipa file. i run fine application in iphone device and simulator. but i can not export ipa file